# Create new sequential column if value in another column is non-unique

Tags: r

I have two columns `x` and `y`, I am trying to create a new sequenced column `z` if the value in one of the columns is non-unique. e.g.

```
x <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", "6", "6")
y <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y")
df <- data.frame(x, y)
```

What I would like to get is the following:

```
#    x     y         z
#
#    1     Y         1
#    1     Y         2
#    1     Y         3
#    1     Y         4
#    2     N         1
#    2     N         2
#    2     Y         3
#    3     Y         1
#    3     Y         2
#    3     Y         3
#    4     Y         1
#    4     Y         2
#    5     Y         1
#    6     N         1
#    6     Y         2
#    6     Y         3
```

Comment: Try `ave(df$x, df$x, FUN = seq_along)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running count based on field in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259932/running-count-based-on-field-in-r)

Comment: No that question is different. Darren thank you, I will include your answer as accepted answer.

Comment: I was able to solve your question with the top answer from my linked one.

Comment: @QHarr yes, I understand what you mean, I guess your link the first row wasn't ordered, hence I didn't understand, but Darren's makes more sense to me. Thanks

Comment: @DarrenTsai how can I create an interval in the sequences, e.g. if I wanted 2,4,6 instead of 1,2,3.

Comment: Maybe `ave(df$x, df$x, FUN = \(x) seq(2, by = 2, len = length(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y <- c("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y")
df <- data.frame(x, y) 

df$z <- ave(df$x, df$x, FUN = seq_along)
```

gives

```
   x y z
1  1 Y 1
2  1 Y 2
3  1 Y 3
4  1 Y 4
5  2 N 1
6  2 N 2
7  2 Y 3
8  3 Y 1
9  3 Y 2
10 3 Y 3
11 4 Y 1
12 4 Y 2
13 5 Y 1
14 6 N 1
15 6 Y 2
16 6 Y 3
```